# Coldfusion/Oracle - Inserted BLOB Value is Returning an Empty String

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, oracle11g, blob, coldfusion-8

Using coldfusion 8, blob values selected from a table are appearing as "[empty string]".

Is there a mistake in my cfml or is there another issue?

I appreciate the help!

ColdFusion Server - 8,0,1,195765

Oracle Database 11g - 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit

BLOB test -

```
<cfset idval="1">
<cfset val="hello world">
<cfset encoding="utf-8">

<!---STRING CONVERSION TO BINARY DATA--->
<cfset form.binVal = CharsetDecode(val,encoding)>
<cfdump var="#form.binVal#">

<!---CLEAR TABLE--->
<cfquery name="delete" datasource="DATA1">
DELETE FROM DATA1.TEST_BLOB
</cfquery>

<!---INSERT--->
<cfquery name="insert" datasource="DATA1">
INSERT INTO DATA1.TEST_BLOB 
VALUES(<cfqueryparam value="#idval#">,
       <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BLOB" value="#form.binVal#">
      )
</cfquery>

<!---SELECT AND DISPLAY DATA--->
<cfquery name="select" datasource="DATA1">
SELECT *
FROM DATA1.TEST_BLOB
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#select#">
```

Comment: When you query the table via an external tool, does it have any data in it? We need to pin down if the `insert` failed, or the `select` failed

Comment: Thanks James, using Oracle Sql Developer - "SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(FILETEXT)) 
from DATA1.TEST_BLOB;", "hello world" is returned.  So the insert is working.

Comment: is there a commit somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `utl_raw.cast_to_Varchar2()` is needed to get results:

```
<cfquery name="select" datasource="DATA1">
  SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(*name_of_field*)) 
  FROM   DATA1.TEST_BLOB
</cfquery>
```

**OR**

To return the data without casting

Go to the CF admin setting for the DSN, there are advanced setting that enable BLOB data

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought the cfdump would return the binary value at least, thanks James!

Comment: James, something I forgot to mention, BLOB and CLOB were enabled for the datasource which didn't change the output.  The cast definitely works though -

Comment: You might want to work this up into a new question. I have seen CF return raw binary on SQL Servers.

Comment: @user2983696 - It returns a string yes, but wasn't your question how to return *binary*? If not, you might want to revise the title/question so the answer better fits the question.